# How to update row after every 12 hour in PHP MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, sql-update

I want to run a script after every 12 hour passes of data entry in table.
I used cron job for this.

actually i am new to php mysql and i made below query to check if its working or not.

so, it is working below is the code.

```
$sql = "UPDATE notification SET yes = 1 WHERE yes = 0 and time >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY"
```

this code is working fine for 24 hour but i want it to work for 12 hour and can't understand how to do it.

it will be very great if anybody can help me in this problem.

Comment: Cron for every 12 hours should be 0 */12 * * *

Comment: `INTERVAL 12 HOUR` would be my guess..

Comment: you want the cronjob to run every 12 hours or update the notifications that are 12 hours old?

Comment: The [Mysql Manual where it describes all the INTERVAL options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: sorry i think my question is bit confusing. i want to update the row after 12 hours of its inserting.

Comment: `and time >= now() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do using [scheduled events](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/), but if you want to use cron and execute every 12 hours, try this

```
$sql = "UPDATE notification SET yes = 1 WHERE yes = 0 and time >= now() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR"
```